# How to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText? in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i want to hide keyboard when user torches outside the Edit text but is not from activity but from fragment please any possible solution

Comment: Please be a more specific with what you need, and show us what you've already tried (eg looekd at other answers from stackoverflow, tutorials etc)

Comment: thank you sir the problem is solved already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get EditTesxt focus status with `setOnFocusChangeListener` and if it's not focused hide the keyboard:

```
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: If it works, please accept and vote up my answer.